Migrating Stored Procedures Using Alembic
I am using an Alembic project to migrate my database schema between my development and production servers.
I am autogenerating my migration scripts by maintaining a models.py containing the SQLAlchemy models for my tables and then running the following command anytime an update is made to the schema:
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "<description of the change>"

My models.py file looks something like this:
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String


Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'sda'}

    customer_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    ...

And this is my env.py:
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

from models import Base

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# set the database URL from environment variables
db_conn_uri = f"mssql+pyodbc://{os.environ['MSSQL_ID']}:{os.environ['MSSQL_PASSWORD']}@{os.environ['MSSQL_SERVER']}/{os.environ['MSSQL_DATABASE']}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal&Encrypt=yes&TrustServerCertificate=no"
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', db_conn_uri)

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()

This works fine, but I would also like to migrate my stored procedures from development to production. How exactly can I do that with the above setup?
I came across the concept of Replaceable Objects in the Alembic cookbook here, but it does not make much sense to me, to be honest.

One of the ways is to manually define the stored procedure in a file, add upgrade/downgrade methods, and call it in the migration.
File with stored procedures:
from alembic import op

stored_procedures = {
    "my_stored_procedure": """
    CREATE PROCEDURE sda.stored_procedure
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM sda.customer;
    END
    """
}

def sp_upgrade():
    for proc_name, proc_sql in stored_procedures.items():
        op.execute(proc_sql)

def sp_downgrade():
    for proc_name in stored_procedures.keys():
        op.execute(f"DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS {proc_name}")

Migration script with direct call to stored_procedures upgrade/downgrade methods:
"""Revision identifier"""

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from stored_procedures import sp_upgrade, sp_downgrade

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'revision_id'
down_revision = 'previous_revision_id'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

def upgrade():
    sp_upgrade()


def downgrade():
    sp_downgrade()

